# Select list not firing jquery on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was previously using the following HTML code for a dropdownlist:

```
<select id="customDropDown" name="mydropdown">
  <option value="CourseIDFilter"id ="1" class ="choosefilter" >Course ID  </option>
  <option value="CourseNameFilter"  id ="2" class ="choosefilter">Course Name</option>
  <option value="ExpiryDateFilter"  id ="3" class ="choosefilter">Expiration Date</option>
  <option value="AuthorFilter" id ="4" class ="choosefilter">Author</option>
</select>
```

From this I was using the following JavaScript to deal with the selection from the dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.choosefilter').click(function (event) {
    var id = event.target.id
    var fullPath = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme://@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host' + '@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath';
    var urlstring = 'Profile/ActiveCoursesList/' + id;
    var path = fullPath.concat(urlstring);

    $.get(urlstring, function (data) {
      $('#ActiveCourses').html(data);
    });

    event.cancelBubble = true;
    event.returnValue = false;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

  });
});
```

Due to some changes in the design of the select the HTML is now as follows:

```
<form class="custom">
  <label for="customDropdown">You can filter your courses below:</label>
  <select style="display:none;" id="customDropdown">
    <option value="CourseIDFilter"id ="1" class ="choosefilter" >Course ID  </option>
    <option value="CourseNameFilter"  id ="2" class ="choosefilter">Course Name</option>
    <option value="ExpiryDateFilter"  id ="3" class ="choosefilter">Expiration Date</option>
    <option value="AuthorFilter" id ="4" class ="choosefilter">Author</option>  
  </select>

  <div class="custom dropdown open" style="width: 192px;">
    <a href="#" class="current">Order by:</a>
    <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
    <ul style="width: 190px;">
      <li class="selected">Course ID</li>
      <li>Course Name</li>
      <li>Expiration Date</li>
      <li>Author</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any ideas as to why my jQuery is no longer firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new variant your select is actually hidden, because of *style="display:none;"*. So, if you don't show it somewhere and try to click on the *li* element will not lead to any results. So, I guess that you should use:

```
$('.dropdown li').on('click', ...
```

Also, when you use dropdown element you should attach a listener to the *change* event of the *select* tag, not *click* event of its options.

```
$('#customDropdown').on('change', function() {
   var id = $(this).find(":selected").attr("id");
})
```

Comment: I am able to get to the onchange of the the customdropdown using your suggestion but I am unable to return any id for this the way my previous dropdown was working

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('#customDropdown').on('change', function(event){ ... }
```

instead of

```
$('.choosefilter').click(function(event) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I see your IDs are different in the second one `customDropdown` vs `customDropDown`